# Where is the proper place to put code that saves objects to sharedpreference file

Tags: java, android

I guess this is a fairly generic object oriented question,  but I am coming to the conclusion that I don't think enough in terms of objects.

I have two classes, a Person class and a People class.  I will be reading and writing these  (from and to the sharedPerferencesFile) from several activities.  Right now I have a PersistData class that handles reading and writing.  When I want to read or write these guys I get an instance of the PersistData class and then call methods like,  persistData.write(person); or persistData.write(people);
Is this a good way to do this,  or should I move the read and write code into the Person and People class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use a class i call settingsprovider, calling something like `new SettingsProvider(this).getPerson();` and `new SettingsProvider(this).setPerson(person); so yes, this is exactly how i would do it.`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks to be correct. SharedPreference is a common file which is shared by all the components in the process. I mean all the classes in an application. So, your way of keeping PersistData and accessing it from person and people class looks clean and right approach.

As sharedPreference is a singlefile so the data will reamin persistant.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you see / define the responsibilites of your classes. A `Person` does not necessarily need to know how to store it in shared preferences so something like `Person#saveToPrefs()` could be seen as bad design (tight coupling to shared preferences)

`PersistData` on the other hand does not need to know how the serialized format of a person looks in detail so that approach has it's weakness here.

I guess the cleanest way is to split the whole thing. A class that knows how to store stuff into shared preferences and a class that knows how to create serialized data of itself but does not care how that serialized data is used.